# Logically equivalent propositions

Tags: logic

Suppose that two propositions are logically equivalent. Are their negations equivalent too? I would say that the answer is yes, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: You are correct.  If they are equivalent, then they are both true or both false, so their negations are both false, or both true.

Comment: If you are new to logic as I am, you will first see a statement similar to that provided by saulspatz.  I finally got to a point in the book I am using that shows a proof.  Good luck!